# Cani I use php loop in xml file?

Tags: php, xml

Can i use php loops in xml file to list out a list of number incremented file names such as file 1.jpg file2.jpg file3.jpg etc to save me having to manually typing it out. 
If so, how do I do this and what doctype etc would the xml file need to have to make it display the loop?

Comment: What is your desired output?  What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a little vague, I can't work out if you're trying to read an XML file or write to it.

Assuming you want to read an XML file, and assuming your XML looks a little like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<rootnode>
  <images>
    <image>file_1.jpg</image>
    <image>file_2.jpg</image>
    <image>file_3.jpg</image>
  </images>
</rootnode>
```

you could use SimpleXML to either load the XML file or to load the XML as a string and then return an object to loop through.
http://php.net/manual/en/ref.simplexml.php

Your PHP might look something like this:

```
if (file_exists('test.xml')) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('test.xml');

    foreach($xml->images AS $image) {
        echo $image;
    }
} else {
    exit('Failed to open test.xml.');
}
```

Comment: Just want to know if there is a simple way of producing a list of file names in an xml file such as 
file1.jpg
file2.jpg
file3.jpg
using say a php loop instead of me having to list out from file1.jpg upto file80.jpg
thanks

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is point to a .php file that outputs XML. All you need to do that is send a header("Content-Type: text/xml"); and make sure you add the  at the top of your output.

Here's an example:

```
    <?php

    header("Content-Type: text/xml");

    print "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>";

    print "<rootNode>";

    for(your loop stuff here) {
        print "<node>" . $yourDataHere . "</node>";
    }

    print "</rootNode>";

    ?>
```